# Remember scroll position on navigating back to first page from second one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

if we are having a page which is loading content by ajax on scrolling to bottom,if we click on any link on scrolling down to some position on page and navigate to next page.And when from next page,I press the button ,i want the page to go to same position from where i cliked.
Please guide me how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

On navigating to second page you can send position via QueryString and get that queryString on another page using javascript and vice versa similarly.Lets say you navigated on page2 like **'page2.html?position=44'** Here is the code to get queryString:

JavaScript:

```
function getQueryString(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Usage: `var position = getQueryString('position');`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes think offset as any variable and send it as queryString.

Comment: I m sorry,but i m not able to understand the queryString concept.Can u please elaborate on this.

Comment: When you are navigating to any other page you must be doing something like go on **"page2.html"** so now you have to go on page2.html and also want to send some variable value as a queryString so now you will go to **"page2.html?position=55"** instead. and on page2 you will be able to get this position by using above function .Here position is a query string . I hope you get my point?

Comment: k.k.got that.then when i m coming back from second page to the respective position how to do that sir??

Comment: You will do the same from page2 i.e. when you got that value of position on second page , suppose you got the value 55 from page1 you'll send that value back on **"page1.html?position=55"** and get the position on page1 using the same above function.

Comment: k.i got that.when u click back from next page for previous one,need to get that string in above function.but how to pass the position value if back button of window is pressed,I want to go back with back button only sir.